# Make plot legend with latex equations and other elements

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, legend, tex

I'm trying to put together latex equations in my legend with other elements but don't know how to do it. I only have my latex equation in legend by the time.

```
l=legend({'$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$'});
        set(l,'Interpreter','Latex')
```

but I also want to add:

```
legend([ num2str(steps) ' steps taken'])
```

anyone any ideas?

I'm working with R2016a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any strings not using latex, format them first.

```
s = sprintf('%d steps taken', steps);
```

Then make a cell array combining the latex and other strings in the correct order

```
c = {'$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$', s};
```

Now this cell array can be used in the legend together with the latex interpreter.

```
l=legend(c); 
set(l,'Interpreter','Latex');
```

Because the strings are also valid latex without special symbols, they should render correctly.